# Why does importing a class make this code fail?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a real beginner in javascript / React...but I'm trying to set-up a tag based on a string value. Why does widget1 fail to get instantiated? (I get an uncaught ReferenceError: FooA is not defined error) What difference does importing the react component make, versus defining it in the same file?

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

// Assume FooA and FooB have identical definitions
import FooA from './fooa.jsx'

class FooB extends Component {
    render() {
         return(<p>Hello A</p>);
    }
};

class Splash extends Component {
    render() {
        var widget1 = eval('new ' + "FooA")
        var widget2 = eval('new ' + "FooB")
        return (
            <div>
                {(widget1.render())}
                {(widget2.render())}
            </div>
         )
    };
}

ReactDOM.render(<Splash/>, container);
```

I am passing this through webpack to get a single .js file.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: did you exported any class in fooa.jsx?. Post content of it also.

Comment: you dont have to execute render manually neither instantiate componets. just use it so: <FooA />

Comment: Yes. I have "export default FooA" in my other file. On the second point "FooA" is held as a string - so would code <widget1/>  work?

Comment: how is "held as a string"? I cant get your point...

Comment: I hold the label of the component I want to display in a string variable (it has been generated elsewhere). I don't want to write a large switch statement of all possible react components it would map to, just insert the react component of the same name.

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to instantiate Components, React does that for you.

Your Splash component should look like this:

```
class Splash extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <FooA />
                <FooB />
            </div>
         )
    };
}
```

Now lets supouse you want to have some logic to determine which component must be rendered:

```
class Splash extends Component {
    let comp = (<FooA />);
    if(some condition)
      comp = (<FooB />);

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {comp}
            </div>
         )
    };
}
```

Now let supouse you want just to parametrize the text:

```
class FooA extends Component {
    render() {
         return(<p>this.props.textToShow</p>);
    }
};

class Splash extends Component {
    let text = 'whatever text you want to show';
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
              <FooA textToShow={text}/>
            </div>
         )
    };
}
```

You can pass as a prop other components as well:

```
class FooA extends Component {
    render() {
         return(
           <p>Some text</p>
           {this.props.child}
         );
    }
};

class FooAChild extends Component {
    render() {
         return(
           <p>I am a child</p>
         );
    }
};

class Splash extends Component {
    let child = (<FooAChild />);
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <FooA child={child}/>
            </div>
         )
    };
}
```

Comment: That's a solution I have considered, but I wanted to avoid writing that logic (imagine I have 100 components). So I wanted the string to hold the 'name' of the component I want, and insert that component. If I have all my components defined in the same file as this code it works, as per the pseudo code.

Comment: I do believe you cant avoid that logic. There is no way (unless something new has been released and I dont realize yet) to use React's components.

Comment: The String variable is not holding text I want to show, it is the name of a react component I want to insert. The bizarre thing is it works, if all the component classes are defined in the same file. It's when I move them off to separate files the code then breaks.

Comment: @PhilipPegden: If you want to make your code generic, you can pass values (including other components!) into your component as props, or write a function that returns a component - storing component names as strings is not a good plan.

Comment: As @JoeClay said, sooner or later you will have to have a switch, or a condition, to determine the component...

Comment: Let me explain why...I am implementing a hybrid between multi and single page app. All the routing is handled by my server side (a Swift Vapor app). I have some involved security / permissions logic that I want to keep there. When the user makes a call say https://myapp.com/foo.html, a route will be set up on the server side. After passing thru some middleware to handle security, it will then return the same html template, which has a small .js code to extract the /foo path and which is used by the react "App" component to select a react component to render.

Comment: so why dont you flag the component and let App render based on that flag?

Answer (score 1):

You're coming at this problem from the wrong angle. If you want to make a component able to render other components in a generic, reusable way, there's three approaches you can take:

## Pass the component class as a prop

```
class Splash extends Component {
    render() {
        let heading = this.props.heading;

        // These have to start with a capital letter, otherwise
        // JSX assumes 'widget1' is a normal HTML element.
        let Widget1 = this.props.widget1;
        let Widget2 = this.props.widget2;

        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{heading}</h1>
                <Widget1 />
                <Widget2 />
            </div>
         )
    };
}

// This can then be used like so:

<Splash heading="My Generic Splash" widget1={FooA} widget2={FooB} />
```

## Pass the component instance as a prop:

```
class Splash extends Component {
    render() {
        let heading = this.props.heading;

        let widget1 = this.props.widget1;
        let widget2 = this.props.widget2;

        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{heading}</h1>
                {widget1}
                {widget2}
            </div>
         )
    };
}

// This can then be used like so:

let fooA = <FooA />;

<Splash heading="My Generic Splash" widget1={fooA} widget2={<FooB />} />
```

## Pass the components as children:

```
class Splash extends Component {
    render() {
        let heading = this.props.heading;

        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{heading}</h1>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
         )
    };
}

// This can then be used like so:

<Splash heading="My Generic Splash">
    <FooA />
    <FooB />
</Splash>
```

Comment: Many thanks! This looks like the solution I need - but one question, when I try it, it doesn't appear to substitute <widget1 /> with the this.props.widget1. When I look in the output I still see <widget1 />, and the this.props.widget1 holding "FooA". Do you think this might be to do with my webpack build settings?

Comment: @PhilipPegden: Ah, whoops, that's a mistake in my code - if you try to create a JSX element using a lower case name, it's assumed to be a standard HTML element. Will update my answer.

Comment: @PhilipPegden: It's also worth noting that you can also pass instances of components rather than the class (e.g. `<Splash widget1={<Foo1 />} />`) and then render them just using the normal `{widget1}` syntax.

Comment: @PhilipPegden: Answer updated to be a bit more comprehensive :)

Comment: @PhilipPegden: Hm - just a hunch, but is Webpack configured to run the Babel loader for `jsx` files?

Comment: Joe. I've taken your code verbatim, and it works ;-)   My issue is when I try and pass in those names via String variables...ReactDOM.render(<Splash heading="My Generic Splash" widget1={("FooA")} widget2={FooB} />, container); FooA doesn't render, FooB does.

Comment: I think my web pack is configured correctly...loaders: [{
    include: DEV,
    loader: "babel-loader",
    }]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142298/discussion-between-philip-pegden-and-joe-clay).